# How to obtain client MAC, ip and other information in the 'ws.on('connection')' callback function?

Tags: websocket, ws

This is the ws module, what I want to ask is how to get the client's MAC, ip and other information when connecting

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const WebSocketServer = WebSocket.Server;
const wss = new WebSocketServer({
  //...
}, () => {
});
wss.on('connection', function (ws, req) {}); //How to get client MAC, ip and other information?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "other information", but `req` is an [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage), so the documentation would be a good starting point.

For example, the IP address is accessible as `req.socket.localAddress`.

You won't be able to get the MAC address.